# Sublime sftp connects to wrong container

Tags: macos, docker, sublimetext3, sftp, osx-elcapitan

I have two different Docker containers under the same host stack.

Currently I'm on OSX and using Sublime Text 3 with the SFTP plugin.

For each different dev environment (Docker container) I have a different `sftp-config.json`file and I am using different SSH key files.

Here are my host entries for both files:

first host:

`"host": "example-dev.xxx.de",
"user": "userxxx",
"remote_path": "/home/xxx/www_trunk",
"ssh_key_file": "~/work/Misc/pass/private1.pem"`

second host:

`"host": "example2-dev.xxx.de",
"user": "userxxx",
"remote_path": "/home/xxx/www_trunk",
"ssh_key_file": "~/work/Misc/pass/private2.pem"`

But when I try to connect to the second host, I always end up on the fist one.

I had the same problem with the OSX terminal before, until I added "IdentitiesOnly YES" to the SSH config file, then I connected to the correct dev environment.

Is there any setting similar to "IdentitiesOnly YES" that I need to add to the `sftp-config.json` files, so that my sublime text also connects to the correct dev environment?

Comment: I doubt that you actually run two containers using the same IP address. Are they sharing the host stack?

Comment: @Auzias, yes, that's what I mean. Sorry, I'm more of a frontend guy, so I sometimes get mixed up with the correct terminology of the dev op's stuff..

Comment: I can't get the question/issue straight. Could you please edit your question?

Comment: @Auzias I edited my question. I hope you can understand it better now. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your effort!

Comment: I cannot pin point where does the problem stem from but I am pretty sure that this has nothing to do with docker. Does the hosts are listening on a different port? (impossible otherwise, but still worth asking to make sure you checked the port). Can you `ssh` into these different containers? [Note that it is a very bad practice to run ssh in a container -- according to a Docker engineer who wrote this blog post.](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/)!