# Edit files in a Docker container ("remote") from Sublime Text on local machine using SFTP

Tags: docker, sublimetext3, sftp

Currently I am editing files inside of a Docker container using `vim`, but I am hoping there is a better way.

According to my research, it seems the best way to edit the files inside of a Docker container on the text editor of one's local machine, Sublime Text for instance, would be to use [Sublime SFTP](https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp).

This requires editing the `sftp-config.json` file, it looks something like this:

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "sync_same_age": true,

    "host": "192.168.129.8",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "666",
    //"port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/",
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    //"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

However- not exactly like that- as that arrangement doesn't work.

The major impediment seems to be that it's not recommended (*not possible?*) at `ssh` into a docker container, at least not using macOS.

[This is a similar unanswered question from one year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340195/sublime-sftp-connects-to-wrong-container).

**QUESTION:**

How can we edit files inside of a Docker container using Sublime Text on our local machine? If SFTP is a viable option, how can we configure `sftp-config.json` and launch a Docker container that can make this possible?

Comment: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Comment: yeah- I've seen that- but does that mean it's impossible?

Comment: Of course it's not impossible. Docker isn't anything magical. If you want to run an ssh server inside your docker container you can certainly do that, at the cost of some complexity.  But more importantly, if you find you have to regularly edit files inside a container I would argue that you are Doing It Wrong. Docker images should be the artifacts of a build process; you edit your files on your host using your favorite tools and then you build a new image and boot it. If you need to make changes, you build a new image.

Comment: what I want to do is create a hadoop cluster in docker containers- my development environment is a mac, so I need to iteratively tinker with the settings of the configuration file parameters, and I'd prefer to do that in Sublime Text, which has all the text completion, and syntax highlighting that I'm familiar with- rather than vim or something that I have to run inside of the container

Comment: [Cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/6yi7v5/edit_files_in_a_docker_container_remote_from/).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is you can't FTP into a server that is not running an FTP daemon. However, there are a couple of alternatives that might work for you.

### Volumes

You could use a custom `docker run` for development purposes, so that your configurations are exposed to the host machine. You could do something like this:

```
docker run \
    -v `pwd`/sftp-config.json:/etc/sftp/sftp-config.json \
    myimage
```

You can do that with whole folders too, if that is appropriate. The format is `<hostfile>:<containerfile>`, and I seem to recall they need to be fully-qualified paths (hence the `pwd`).

What happens here is that the image containing the built version of `sftp-config.json` is overwritten with a volume that dynamically reflects the state of the specified host copy.

In some cases, live environments can be set up like this ([Traefik, for example](https://store.docker.com/images/traefik)) so that a configuration file on the host is used inside a container. However, it's worth remembering that the point of Docker is to create standalone images that have passed through a CI process. Thus, the more dependencies you move to the host for convenience reasons, the more brittle and untested they become.

Out of interest, I use volumes when developing, so that I don't need to go through a rebuild/restart cycle for every small change. I create a volume for every critical folder in my app, which hugely speeds up the modify-and-try loop. Of course, this does not replace a proper build/CI process, nor is it run like this in live:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Note the web service is on port 8080

PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/missive_controller

docker run \
    --detach \
    -p 10000:8080 \
    -p 10002:8081 \
    -v $(pwd)/bin:${PROJECT_ROOT}/bin \
    -v $(pwd)/src:${PROJECT_ROOT}/src \
    -v $(pwd)/vendor:${PROJECT_ROOT}/vendor \
    -v $(pwd)/web:${PROJECT_ROOT}/web \
    missive-controller
```

I do the same with definitions in a dev-only `docker-compose.yml` as well, it works very nicely.

### Shelling in

If you want to make quick changes to a container during development, you probably don't want to SSH in - mostly because images generally ought not to be running the SSH daemon. However, you can shell in easily:

```
docker exec -it <containername> sh
```

where `sh` is the name of your shell. BusyBox distributions tend to go for `sh`, whereas Ubuntu-based containers will probably have `bash` available.

From there, you can make changes using an in-container editor. During the early development phase of a container, I tend to leave `RUN apk --update add nano` in my Dockerfile (and of course it gets removed as the development settles down).

### Layered FS

To wrap up some clarifications in the comments, it is worth thinking of Docker images as:

- Immutable;
- Versioned;
- Produced by a CI/build process and only promoted if they pass automated functional testing;
- Composed of filing system layers

The last point is critical to understanding images, I think. When you do `docker build` it adds a layer per command, which is why intermediate and unchanged layers can be retrieved from cache rather than rebuilt every time.

When you add a volume, you can think of this as another layer on top, with the exception that the change is not permanent. Consider these steps:

- Image 1234 contains a file `/etc/mywidget.conf` containing "a=1"
- This is created from a file on your host, in your project, called `conf/mywidget.conf`, which you `COPY` to the container in your `Dockerfile`
- If you modify the file in your host, it does not change the copy in your container until you rebuild
- Thus, if you change your host copy to "a=2", and then restart your container, it will still see the old copy;
- However, if you create a volume `-v /path/to/conf/mywidget.conf:/etc/mywidget.conf` and restart your container, it will see the host version of "a=2";
- You can think of this volume as a new layer atop the built version of the container
- If you restart the container and remove the volume, it will go back to the build version of "a=1"
- Finally, if you rebuild the image and then restart it, it will `COPY` the new state of the file into the image, so it will see "a=2" even without the volume.

Comment: so I think with the edit you just made, we're now on the same page- the whole point is that I don't want to use `nano` because it doesn't have any of the syntax highlighting or auto-completion that I like to use when I build software, I want to iteratively get the container to where I want it to be, in terms of configuration, installing things and so on, in my normal dev environment, then commit it/freeze it for good, and push it to the docker hub- you know what I mean?

Comment: Sure @s.matthew. So, using `nano` is in-container, so is probably not what you want. Use the `-v` volume approach during development, and then when you are happy with the config file, rebuild your image and it will contain the latest copy, assuming your `Dockerfile` uses `COPY` to add that config file to the image. In non-dev envs, you can remove the `-v` option and it will fall back to the container copy.

Comment: If you want the ability to edit files on the host, even in live, then you can use the volume approach for all envs. Just bear in mind the "brittleness" trade-off I have mentioned.

Comment: for brittleness- that just means I need to commit the image before I exit, isn't it? so- I'm still not sure what this volume thing is all about, when I did that before it seemed it was just mounting files from my host machine into my container- so for instance I would have my local macos `~/Desktop` on my ubuntu image container, are you saying that I should replicate the folders that I want to develop with, delete them off of my container, just have then on the host machine and then save then when they're configuered how I like?

Comment: for example- if there's some imaginary folder called `hadoop` that lives in my image, I would create also a folder called `hadoop` on my local machine, then I would start the image and delete the container's own version of the `hadoop` folder, replacing it with my local version, like that?

Comment: Not quite. Your container's `hadoop` is the version that was `COPY`d into the image last time you did a `docker build`. If you do not have a volume flag, it will use that. However if you have a volume flag, the `hadoop` folder will be automatically overwritten with the dynamic volume. However if you run it a third time without the volume flag, it will go back to the build-time version. So, you don't need to do any deleting - it is done all for you by the volume subsystem.

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of images as things that need to be saved/preserved, but they should be regarded as static. If a container generates data that should be preserved (e.g. logs) it should be put in a volume anyway. Images should be regarded as versionable artefacts in order to reduce brittleness. If an image keeps changing, then it will effectively bypass your CI, leaving you open to production failures. (No time to chat, sorry).

Comment: so then, what do you use for editing containers before you cryogenically freeze them- are you- an old school `vim` hacker and you have it super tricked out for editing containers or something? I can't imagine you putzing around editing things in `nano`

Comment: No, mostly I just use my IDE - NetBeans. For me, there's nothing really about container-based development that makes it altogether different from not using containers. Obviously there is a bit of management overhead, and I tend to rebuild every couple of days to make sure the `Dockerfile` still works, but that's it. That said, I do still sometimes shell into a running container to check things I don't have a volume for.

Comment: man I looked into volumes- so here is exactly the problem `when you use a volume, a new directory is created within Docker’s storage directory on the host machine, and Docker manages that directory’s contents` - i have macos, but my containers are ubuntu- I want to download hadoop for ubuntu and change the configuration for my containers, and I want it to be the version of hadoop downloaded from the ubuntu package manager, not the one from homebrew- do you see what I mean?

Comment: Sure. You don't need Hadoop on your Mac for this. Get your container running without `-v` and then copy the configuration file from your container build to your host (something like `docker cp mycontainer:/etc/hadoop/hadoop.conf \`pwd\`/hadoop.conf`, obviously switching the container name and paths as appropriate for your case). Then stop the container, restart it with `-v`, with the volume in place to dynamically overwrite the container version with your on-host version.

Comment: All the above presumes that you have installed Hadoop in your Ubuntu container, and have got it running successfully, of course.